# Mysqli object not created

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting an error when trying to connect to creatge a mysqli object using PHP.

File: new_lib.php

```
<?php
namespace Mysql\NewLib;
interface NewLibMethods {
}

class MysqlClient implements NewLibMethods
{
    public $mysql_client = null;
    function __construct ($creds)
    {
        $this->mysql_client = new mysqli($creds['host'], $creds['user'], $creds['pwd'], $creds['db_name']);
    }
}
```

File test1.php

```
<?php
require 'new_lib.php';

$mysql_obj = new Mysql\NewLib\MysqlClient(['host' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'user' => 'xxxxxx',
    'pwd' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'db_name' => 'xxxxxxxx']);
```

When I run test1.php, I get the following error message:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.10/bin/php /Users/jim/new_lib/test_1.php

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Mysql\NewLib\mysqli" not found in /Users/jim/new_lib/new_lib.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/jim/new_lib/test_1.php(4): Mysql\NewLib\MysqlClient->__construct(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/jim/new_lib/new_lib.php on line 12
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Mysql\NewLib\mysqli" not found in /Users/jim/new_lib/new_lib.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/jim/new_lib/test_1.php(4): Mysql\NewLib\MysqlClient->__construct(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/jim/new_lib/new_lib.php on line 12

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't `use mysqli`, or use `\mysqli`, so... sure? Any function/namespace you don't explicitly import gets resolved to the namespace you declared. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php and all its subpages are worth a careful read-through. Specifically https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php is important for this particular question, but give the other pages a thorough read, too.

Comment: Adding the mysqli namespace to my namespace took care of the issue